# UnsatisfiedDependencyException during Spring Injection

Tags: spring

I am getting this error for using Spring injection using constructor argument:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'testIdCreator': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[IdCreatorDao]: : No matching bean of type [com.dao.IdCreatorDao
```

Bean definition:

```
<bean id="testIdCreator" class="com.utils.TestIdCreator">
    <constructor-arg ref="mydDao"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mydDao" class="com.dao.idCreatorDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="somedatasource" />
    <constructor-arg value="${somedatasource.schema}" />
</bean>
```

Bean usage:

```
public class TestIdCreator{
     private final IdCreatorDao idDao;


    @Inject
    public TestIdCreator(IdCreatorDao idDao) {
        this.idDao= idDao;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `com.dao.idCreatorDAOImpl` is not `com.dao.IdCreatorDAOImpl`, also, remove the `@Inject` annotation, with the `<constructor-arg>` is sufficient.

Comment: Leaving the annotation is perfectly fine and helps document the code.

Comment: You have both annotations and XML. How do you bootstrap Spring ?

Comment: Looks a bit strange, I think the problem is not in the so fare posted code. Please post the code of the class `com.utils.TestIdCreator` as well as the COMPLETE Exception (it looks like you cut of something - the most interesting part of an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` is often at its end)

Comment: @Ralph:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'testIdCreator': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[IdCreatorDao]: : No matching bean of type [IdCreatorDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type[IdCreatorDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.